# How to conditionally process FlowFile's by a MongoDB query result?

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to process a list of files based on the result of a MongoDB query, but I can't find any processor that would let me do that. I basically have to take each file and process it or completely discard based on the result of a query that involves that file attributes.

The only MongoDB-related processor that I see in NiFi 1.50 is GetMongo, which apparently can't receive connections, but only emit FlowFiles based on the configured parameters.

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NIFI-4827](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4827) is an Improvement Jira that aims to allow GetMongo to accept incoming flow files, the content would contain the query, and the properties will accept Expression Language. The code is still under review, but the intent is to make it available in the upcoming NiFi 1.6.0 release.

As a possible workaround in the meantime, if there is a REST API you could use [InvokeHttp](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html) to make the call(s) manually and parse the result(s). Also if you have a JDBC driver for MongoDB (such as Unity), you might be able to use [ExecuteSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL/index.html).

Comment: I was just surfing the Apache Jira and arrived at that same issue; thank you for the suggestions, I'll check them.